# How to go back to previous line of a script in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to write a script but I'm stuck here. See the code please!

```
aug@august:~/play$ for i in {1..100..4}
> do
> echo "august"
> touch august $i+$2
> mkdir dir
```

Is there any way to go previous line? I mean there was a mistype, I did in `touch august $i+$2`. Ipressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, so I went for new line. How can I get back to previous line?

Comment: you should write script in a file then run it from terminal. You can also use UP key for previous command, but no way to revert the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash`'s command-line editor doesn't support this, either do as *anwar* suggests or keep everything on one line separated by semicolons or put it into a script file.

On a side note, `zsh` has features that help with this. The `zsh` line editor (`zle`) is a more fully featured editor and supports moving within a multi-line command. When the command becomes too long to handle in `zle` it has a builtin feature, `edit-command-line`, which opens up the command-line in your favorite editor. It's usually not bound, try with:

```
bindkey "^[e" edit-command-line
```

<kbd>Alt-e</kbd> should now activate it, save and quit to go back to the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

After you pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and got an error message, you can just go back in history:

Just press the <kbd>↑</kbd> key in your keyboard to fix the typo. If you press <kbd>↑</kbd> key the terminal will show you this line:

```
for i in {1..100..4}; do echo "august"; touch august $i+$2; mkdir;
```

Correct the mistyped stuff around `touch august $i+$2` and add a  `done` at the end of the command.

Then hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478277), in bash you have Commands for Manipulating the History as stated in it's manual. One of them is `edit-and-execute-command`.

This will open your editor with your commands already typed in a temporary file and you can correct previous lines easily. You can achieve this in emacs mode by `C-xC-e`, and vi mode by pressing `v` in normal mode.

> edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke $VISUAL, $EDITOR,
>   and emacs as the editor, in that order.

Comment: Wow. Years of linux, and I just know this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> from the current `command`.  Then press the <kbd>↑</kbd>. Now you can edit whichever line you want by moving around with the `arrow buttons` - <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Good Luck...